# How to fade a UIVisualEffectView and/or UIBlurEffect in and out?

Tags: ios, swift, fade, uiblureffect, uivisualeffectview

I want to fade a UIVisualEffectsView with a UIBlurEffect in and out:

```
var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
```

I use a normal animation within a function called by a `UIButton` to fade it in, same for fading out but `.alpha = 0` & `hidden = true`:

```
blurEffectView.hidden = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
    self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1
}
```

Now, fading in both directions does work but it gives me an error when fading **out**:

> `<UIVisualEffectView 0x7fdf5bcb6e80>` is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.

**Question**

How do I successfully fade the `UIVisualEffectView` in and out without *breaking* it and having a fading transition?

**Note**

- I tried to put the `UIVisualEffectView` into a `UIView` and fade that one, no success

Comment: You can avoid the Error by:  1. NOT assigning an initial style to the blurEffect.  i.e., var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView() and then 2. assigning the blurEffect to the blurEffectView INSIDE the animation block.  3. animating the "assignment of blurEffect to blurEffectView" is done in place of adjustments to blurEffectView.alpha.   **The error will appear even if you assign an initial value, nil it, then add it back.  So the key to preventing the error is to not assign the effect to blurEffectView until the animation block.

Comment: Also need to mention, the blurEffectView must have alpha=1.0 to avoid the error.  Tampering with alpha in any way will produce the error.  Eg, prior to animation block you set blurEffectView.alpha = 0.7, then in the animationBlock you assign blurEffectView.effect = blurEffect, the error is produced.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I think this is new in iOS9, but you can now set the effect of a `UIVisualEffectView` inside an animation block:

```
let overlay = UIVisualEffectView()
// Put it somewhere, give it a frame...
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    overlay.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
```

Set it to `nil` to remove.

**VERY IMPORTANT - When testing this on the simulator, make sure to set your simulator's Graphics Quality Override to High Quality in order for this to work.**

Comment: You can also set the effect to nil to get a pretty "blur out"

Comment: @jpros Would you mind explaining what you mean by "blur out?"

Comment: Any Idea how not to animated it but to set it to like 50% of the effect?

Comment: This doesn't work. When you play close attention, you see that the blur effect is only added at the end of the animation. A `UIBlurEffect` can't be animated as of iOS10.3. See andrewbuilder's answer below.

Comment: @Manuel it does work. Are you doing it on the simulator or a device (it looks terrible on the simulator)

Comment: @jrturton on the device. I am adding the `UIVisualEffectsView` to the view on `viewDidLoad` and add the `effect` property on `viewWillAppear`. I can see the animation darkening the background, until the final shade, then the blur is added in an instant.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's happening. I have it working in other projects. It's probably best to ask a new question and include your specific setup.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov It works beautifully. You're basically putting a blank `UIVisualEffectView` into a view and animating the effect, which is why you set the effect inside the animation block.

Answer (score 19):

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html) (currently) states...

> When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are less than 1.

and

> Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all.

*I believe some important context is missing here...*

I'd suggest that the intent is to avoid alpha values that are less than 1 for a persistent view. In my humble opinion this does not apply to the animation of a view.

My point - I'd suggest that alpha values less than 1 are acceptable for animations.

The terminal message states:

> UIVisualEffectView is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.

Reading this carefully, the effect will ***appear*** to be broken. My points on this being:

- the apparent break only really matters for a view that is persistent - not changing;
- a persistent / unchanging `UIVisualEffect` view with an alpha value less than 1 will not present as intended / designed by Apple; and
- the message in the terminal is not an error, just a warning.

To extend @jrturton's answer above that helped me solve my problem, I'd add...

To fade out the `UIVisualEffect` use the following (Objective-C) code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
//  EITHER...
    self.blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(nil)
//  OR...
    self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
} )
```

I successfully use both methods: setting the `effect` property to `nil` and setting the `alpha` property to `0`.

Note that setting the `effect` to `nil` creates a "nice flash" (for want of a better description) at the end of the animation, while setting the `alpha` to `0` creates a smooth transition.

(Let me know any syntax errors... I write in obj-c.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I get your point; the error is resolved for me already w/ exactly what you mentioned :)

Answer (score 15):

Here is the solution that I ended up which works on both iOS10 and earlier versions using Swift 3

```
extension UIVisualEffectView {

    func fadeInEffect(_ style:UIBlurEffectStyle = .light, withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .easeIn) {
                self.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
            }

            animator.startAnimation()
        }else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
            }
        }
    }

    func fadeOutEffect(withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear) {
                self.effect = nil
            }

            animator.startAnimation()
            animator.fractionComplete = 1
        }else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.effect = nil
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can also [check this gist](https://gist.github.com/gunhansancar/a5153cd4df9e81dd95ad04731b4ddf43) to find an example usage.

Comment: Using the `UIViewPropertyAnimator` is the only thing that seems to work in iOS 11. Thanks for this!

Comment: Don't forget to add:
import UIKit

Answer (score 8):

Just a workaround - put `UIVisualEffectView` into a container view and change `alpha` property for that container. That approach works perfectly for me on iOS 9. Seems it no longer works in iOS 10.

Comment: Can you provide sample code. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works for me in iOS 9

Comment: @DerrickHunt Same here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @damirstuhec If your project is iOS 10 only, you can use the new UIViewPropertyAnimator class to animate the UIBlurView strength. If you need to support older versions, you can use the above code and the use the #available keyword to use UIViewPropertyAnimator for devices running 10. Hope this helps!

Comment: @DerrickHunt Any Idea how not to animated it but to set it to like 50% of the effect?

Comment: @Georg iOS 10 or lower?

Comment: iOS10... on < iOS it was working by changing the alpha of the container view... but now on iOS10 my interactive blurring is broken :(

Answer (score 5):

You can change the alpha of the visual effects view without any problems, other than the warning in the console. The view may appear as simply partially transparent, rather than blurred. But this usually isn't a problem if you're just changing the alpha during animation.

Your app isn't going to crash or get rejected for this. Test it on a real device (or eight). If you're happy with how it looks and performs, it's fine. Apple's just warning you that it may not look or perform as well as a visual effects view with an alpha value of 1.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a snapshot of a static underlying view, and fade it in and out without touching the opacity of the blur view. Assuming an ivar of blurView:

```
func addBlur() {
    guard let blurEffectView = blurEffectView else { return }

    //snapShot = UIScreen.mainScreen().snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
    let snapShot = self.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    view.addSubview(snapShot)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        snapShot.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        snapShot.removeFromSuperview()
    } )
}

func removeBlur() {
    guard let blurEffectView = blurEffectView else { return }

    let snapShot = self.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
    snapShot.alpha = 0.0
    view.addSubview(snapShot)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        snapShot.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        snapShot.removeFromSuperview()
    } )
}
```

Comment: Nice idea as well but that won't work well for non-static (moving / animating) content beneath the blur view.

Comment: @LinusG. Well, Apple says shouldn't play around with a blur view alpha. You could use a CADisplayLink to grab screen shots of your base view, then render them in a image view (perhaps one you did - real lightweight) - and show those in the top view while changing its opacity to 0. Possible but a lot of work.

Comment: This was the only way (so far) I've been able to achieve what I wanted in iOS 10 - fade in a modal over fullscreen, with a very dark blur effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fade in you UIVisualEffectView - for ios10 use UIViewPropertyAnimator

```
    UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:nil];
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame;
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    UIView *blackUIView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [bacgroundImageView addSubview:blackUIView];
    [blackUIView addSubview:blurEffectView];
    UIViewPropertyAnimator *animator  = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:4.f curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
        [blurEffectView setEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
    }];
```

then you can set percent

```
[animator setFractionComplete:percent];
```

for ios9 you can use alpha component

Comment: The question is specifically tagged "swift", not "objective-c": please provide an answer in Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Objective C Code. I found it handy as there wasn't many other examples listed.

Answer (score 2):

The alpha of the UIVisualEffectView always has to be 1. I think you can achieve the effect by setting the alpha of the background color.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html

Comment: Peter, can you please explain how to set alpha of the background color?

Comment: @borisy use the `colorWithAlphaComponent:` method on the `UIColor` instances.

Not sure how to achieve the same effect with setting the background color, though.

Comment: By changing background alpha component is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following solution, using separate animations for the  `UIVisualEffectView` and the contents. I used the `viewWithTag()` method to get a reference to the `UIView` inside the `UIVisualEffectView`.

```
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
// Fade in
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { self.blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light) }    
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { self.blurEffectView.viewWithTag(1)?.alpha = 1 }
// Fade out
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { self.blurEffectView.effect = nil }    
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { self.blurEffectView.viewWithTag(1)?.alpha = 0 }
```

I would prefer the single animation changing the alpha, but this avoids the error and seems to work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I make an uiview which alpha is 0 and add blurview as subview of that. So i  can hide/show or rounding corners it with animation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and the way I got around it was to house the UIVisualEffectsView in a UIView, and animate that UIView's alpha.

This worked well, except that it as soon as the alpha changed below 1.0 it turned to a solid white and looked very jarring. In order to get around this, you must set the UIView's layer property `containerView.layer.allowsGroupOpacity = false` and this will prevent it from flashing white.

Now you can animate in/fade out the UIView containing the visual effects view and any other subviews using it's alpha property and not have to worry about any graphical glitches or it logging a warning message.

Answer (score 0):

```
_visualEffectView.contentView.alpha = 0;
```

To change the alpha of UIVisualEffectView, you should change the contentView of _visualEffectView.If you change alpha of _visualEffectView, you will get this

```
<UIVisualEffectView 0x7ff7bb54b490> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I only want to animate a blur when I'm presenting a view controller over the screen and want to blur the presenting view controller.  Here's an extension that adds blur() and unblur() to a view controller in order to facilitate that:

```
extension UIViewController {

   func blur() {
       //   Blur out the current view
       let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: self.view.frame)
       self.view.addSubview(blurView)
       UIView.animate(withDuration:0.25) {
           blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
       }
   }

   func unblur() {
       for childView in view.subviews {
           guard let effectView = childView as? UIVisualEffectView else { continue }
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                effectView.effect = nil
           }) {
               didFinish in
               effectView.removeFromSuperview()
           }
       }
   }
}
```

You can of course make this more robust by letting the user choose the effect style, modify the duration, call something when the animation is completed, tag the added visual effect view in blur() to ensure it's the only one removed when you unblur(), etc., but I haven't found the need to do these things so far, since this tends to be a "fire and forget" type of operation.

Comment: "fire and forget" is so relatable! Ha

Answer (score 0):

based on @cc's answer i modified his extension to blur a view

```
extension UIView {

    func blur() {
        //   Blur out the current view
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(blurView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration:0.25) {
            blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        }
    }

    func unblur() {
        for childView in subviews {
            guard let effectView = childView as? UIVisualEffectView else { continue }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
                effectView.effect = nil
            }) {
                didFinish in
                effectView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving @Tel4tel and @cc response, here is an extension with parameters and a brief explanation.

```
extension UIView {

    // Perform a blur animation in the whole view
    // Effect tone can be .light, .dark, .regular...
    func blur(duration inSeconds: Double, effect tone: UIBlurEffectStyle) {
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(blurView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: inSeconds) {
            blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: tone)
        }
    }

    // Perform an unblur animation in the whole view
    func unblur(duration inSeconds: Double) {
        for childView in subviews {
            guard let effectView = childView as? UIVisualEffectView else { continue 
        }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: inSeconds, animations: {
                effectView.effect = nil
            }){
                didFinish in effectView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:
    `view.blur(duration: 5.0, effect: .light)`
or
    `view.unblur(duration: 3.0)`

Remember to NOT use it in `viewDidLoad()` as it will override the animation.
Also, when running on a Simulator, turn the graphics to the Higher level to be able to see the animation (Debug > Graphics Quality Override > High Quality).