# Animate image change of UIImageView when having an UIVisualEffectView above

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uivisualeffectview

My problem is as follows:

An `UIImageView`'s view is going to be changed with an animation, like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:_backgroundArtworkImageView
                  duration:ANIMATION_DURATION
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    _backgroundArtworkImageView.image = blurredImage;
                }
                completion:nil];
```

It works perfectly fine as long as I don't have an `UIVisualEffectView` over the image view. If using the blur view on top, it results in no animation at all.

I've looked around for a bit and seen that [snapshots of views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708699) could be something to look into, which also seems to be what Apple uses internally on iOS, for example when bringing up the app switcher; I'm not really sure how exactly to approach it though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by taking a snapshot, append it to the superview, hide the real view, change it without animation and then fade the real view in with animation.

```
__block UIView *snapshot = [_backgroundArtworkImageView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
[_artworkContainer insertSubview:snapshot belowSubview:_backgroundArtworkImageView];
_backgroundArtworkImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
_backgroundArtworkImageView.image = blurredImage;

[UIView transitionWithView:_artworkContainer
                  duration:ANIMATION_DURATION
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    _backgroundArtworkImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL _) {
                    [snapshot removeFromSuperview];
                    snapshot = nil;
                }];
```

Edit: I realized that the blur view was taking a small time to update, but to solve that a new snapshot of the resulting view could be taken and then animated with.